# Pentaho error: javac: invalid target release: 7

Tags: java, ant, pentaho, javac, monetdb

I'm trying to build pentaho with ant command, but I'm getting this following error

```
compile.compile:
    [javac] Compiling 369 source files to /opt/pentaho-kettle/pentaho-kettle/core/bin/classes
    [javac] javac: invalid target release: 7
    [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    [javac] use -help for a list of possible options

BUILD FAILED
/opt/pentaho-kettle/pentaho-kettle/build.xml:123: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/pentaho-kettle/pentaho-kettle/build.xml:128: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/pentaho-kettle/pentaho-kettle/core/build-res/subfloor.xml:1339: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds
```

I have changed the java before running the application by using below command:

bmartis@bmartis-VirtualBox:/opt/pentaho-kettle/pentaho-kettle$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: what kettle api version do you use in your classes?

Comment: I downloaded pentaho-kettle using the below command:              git clone https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle. I don't know to check the kettle api version. I am following this doc : http://ubiquis.co.uk/pdi/monetdb-bulk-loader-and-pdi/#comment-14

Comment: Hi @aurelius : I think issue was with java and javac version. Both were not same and once I resolved that issue, build is in progress.